# How to compile/package an IE7PRO script as an IE plugin?

Tags: javascript, scripting, greasemonkey

is it possible to compile and package IE7PRO scripts as IE plug-in ? 
I've already developed a script on GreaseMonkey that's working fine under Firefox, and I wanted to port that js script under IE.

- is there any tools or libraries that allows this kind of compilation (.js (IE7PRO) -> IE Plugin) ?
- is there any other solutions like IE7PRO ?

thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can try Grease Monkey for IE. [http://www.gm4ie.com/index.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20110604005854/http://www.gm4ie.com/index.html)

Comment: last release of this tool is 0.1 dated 30/07/2006...
I think they abandoned the project